# Google Keyboard crashing caused by latin input

Tags: crashes, dictionary, gboard

PAC ROM 4.4.4 SGS3 & N7

Google Keyboard keeps crashing with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent
{ act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDEDdat=package:com.snapchat.android flg=0x4000010 (has extras)}
in com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryPacklns1allBroadcastReceiver@43223ccO
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:776)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatehMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygotelnit.java:732)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java:566)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryPacklnstallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(DictionaryPacklnstallBroadcastReceiver.java:91)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:766)
... 10 more
```

This stack trace seems, that it crashes after all updates / app installs.

Comment: Seems the problem is either on SnapChat or Google Keyboard's dictionary, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: I don't think it's Snapchat • think also its the dic